# PHP loading JS video player

Tags: javascript, php, html5-video

So I have this PHP script to show my videos in Fluid Player, it looks like this:

```
    while($video = mysqli_fetch_array($resultat_video, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
        {  
        echo "<video id='video-id'><source src='mov/$video[filnavn]' type='video/mp4' />";
        }
```

Loading  the  Javascript  to load Fluid players looks like this:

```
<script>
    var myFP = fluidPlayer(
        'video-id', {
    "layoutControls": {
        "controlBar": {
            "autoHideTimeout": 3,
            "animated": true,
            "autoHide": true
        },
        "htmlOnPauseBlock": {
            "html": null,
            "height": null,
            "width": null
        },
        "autoPlay": false,
        "mute": true,
        "allowTheatre": true,
        "playPauseAnimation": false,
        "playbackRateEnabled": false,
        "allowDownload": false,
        "playButtonShowing": false,
        "fillToContainer": false,
        "posterImage": ""
    },
    "vastOptions": {
        "adList": [],
        "adCTAText": false,
        "adCTATextPosition": ""
    }
});
</script>
```

This works perfectly for one video, but i guess  I can't call the same ID in  my PHP ID and expet it to work, so I guess  it needs some sort of invidual ID  both in  the PHP and also in the Javascript?

I'm very new to Javascript so all help is apprichiated  alot :)

Regards,
Jan

Comment: _"I guess it needs some sort of individual ID both in the PHP and also in the Javascript"_ That is correct. Each video will need a unique value. If you're lucky, you may already have a unique id field from the database stored in `$video` that you could use.

Comment: yeah, no worries about that. that's the easy part :)

I run it in PHP as id='video-id' can easy add a id that that one.

But on the Javascript side, how do I load it?

Comment: I have no idea how FluidPlayer works, but I'm guessing you could write JS that does something like, for each `video` tag, extract the id attribute and then call fluidPlayer() function passing that id.

Comment: I guess it's the same with loading other Javascripts?

The key is that the JS is runned by this:  

var myFP = fluidPlayer(
        'video-id',

Comment: Also not clear how the player(s) work but you likely could have multiple `var myFP = fluidPlayer( 'video-id', {` calls with the `video-id` iterated so each reference there appropriate div.

Comment: _"The key is that the JS is runned by this"_ Right, you just have to run that code once for each unique video id.

Comment: But in one of my albums I got like 50 videos, I don't want to load the JS 50 times...? 

Video1 = id='video-id-1' -> JS  with the same 'video-id-1 ' works fine...

Comment: Looks like fluidplayer only supports `id`s so I dont see another way to do it easily. You could have JS build the element `<video...` based on the click. Then inject the player JS as well

Comment: mhm, okay. 
That sucks, I liked the player and it worked fine and easy with just one video and I thought it was just my lack of JS skills that was the problem :D

Comment: If you want them chained they support that, https://docs.fluidplayer.com/docs/integration/quick-setup/#quality-switching, but not independent (scroll to top for identifier info).

Comment: Interresting, not a perfect playlist function as I don't "name" the videos I'm adding to my gallery. 

I will play around with it a bit :)

Comment: I don't use FluidPlayer but what's wrong with having one (Fluid) player and simply change the `src` of the `<video>` tag to change the playing video? I don't know how your "gallery" works (_eg:_ does it show image thumbnails that are clicked to play a different video?) but you can access the video element like : `document.getElementById('video-id').src = "your_next_vid_file.mp4"` ... Don't know if that helps you avoid making. multiple players...

Comment: PS: Forgot to mention... After setting source, you must also use `document.getElementById('video-id').load();` to initialise the new video. The Fluid Player  video will at this point change picture according to the new source URL. If you don't `load()` then it appears like it's not working. Just a tip to future readers with a similar problem.